# Build conflicts in ASP.Net with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: asp.net, .net, dll, build

A new message appears in every `Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.4.1` build done now.

```
warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of the same 
  dependent assembly that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are 
  listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.
  ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Stack Overflow told me how to get a more detailed log message which is listed next.  I found three conflicts that I do not know how to resolve. All build objects are added automatically making these quite problems mysterious for a programmer.

**Conflict JSON**

```
There was a conflict between "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 

PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" and "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, 
  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed".
  "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
  PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" was chosen because it was primary and 
  "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
  PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" was not.
References which depend on "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
  PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" 
  [C:\Users\George\OneDrive\SignupList\SignupList\bin\Newtonsoft.Json.dll].
```

The NuGet Package Manager says I only have Newtonsoft.JSON 10.0.3.  How do I get rid of version 8?  There is only one Newtonsoft.Json.dll in bin.  I upgraded to JSON 10 recently, I am surprised Visual Studio did not look after it being called an upgrade.

**Confict mscorlib**

There was a conflict between "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,

```
   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, 
   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes".
   "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
    was chosen because it was primary and "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, 
    Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes" was not.
References which depend on "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
    PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference 
    Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll].
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference 
    Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll
```

No idea what mscorlib.dll is. I have NETFramework folders for v3.5, v4.0, v4.5, v4.5.1, v4.5.2, v4.6, v4.6.1, and v4.X. Where can I control which one is being used for mscorlib.dll and how would I choose?  mscorlib.dll has been a recurring problem over the years in this project.

System.dll seems to be similar to the mscorlib.dll conflict issue.

```
There was a conflict between "System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 

   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "System, Version=2.0.5.0, 
   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes".
  "System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" was `enter code here`
    chosen because it was primary and "System, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, 
    PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes" was not.
References which depend on "System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
    PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference 
    Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.dll].
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling your nuget packages.
We used to get scenarios like this when we used TFS and noobs kept checking in the packages folder.

Execute the following command in nuget package manager console:

```
update-package -reinstall
```

The other common time that erors like this can ocurr is when you change the target platform of your project.

---

If re-install doesn't work, one of your other (non-NuGet, or incorrect NuGet) references is compiled against Newtonsoft.Json v8

> NuGet package authors *should* declare all dependencies, including references to Newtonsoft.Json... When they do so, NuGet will not let you install a higher version of a package unless it is compatible with all the existing packages. That reinstall usually works, it forces the dependencies to be re-evaluated against the current framework. Unfortunately, it is pretty easy to get the dependency definitions wrong in the NuGet manifest, or to omit them altogether.

Try using assembly binding mapping in web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Tried it, but it did not help.  I would have thought it would solve the JSON version problem.

Comment: Got a new solution for you this time :) lets focus on one reference at a time, most likely the same solution to all of them. Are any of the references your own external projects?